# RequestMethod.PUT = error 403

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I'm actually trying to create some REST controllers but each time that I try to use the PUT method I get a 403 error while the GET and DELETE method work fine.

here is my servlet-context.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

             xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Anable du model @Controller -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Résolution des vues utilisées (renvoyées) par les controller - Rendu/Intepretation JSP -->
    <beans:bean id="viewReslover" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"></beans:bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="back_office" />

</beans:beans>
```

here is my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>



    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>

        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>



    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LogIn</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.LogIn</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LogOut</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.LogOut</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Registration</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.RegistrationServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LogIn</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/log_in</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LogOut</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/log_out</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Registration</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/registration</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/back_office</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/back_office/users</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/back_office/user_update</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/back_office/user</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/back_office/salon_message</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/back_office/salon_nbr_message</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/back_office//addMessage</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/back_office/message</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/back_office/delSalon</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>filtre_connexion</filter-name>
        <filter-class>Filtre.Connexion</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>filtre_connexion</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

and here is one of my controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/back_office/addMessage", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<String> addMessage(@RequestParam(value = "salon", required = true) String salon,
        @RequestBody String message)
    {
    Tchat t = new Tchat();
    t.add_Message(message, salon, "god");

         return new ResponseEntity<String>("resource saved", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I'm a newbie on java so I may have missed something but I'm stuck on this for a few day now and I have no idea on why it don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this correct:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/back_office**//addMessage**</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Looks like it should be:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/back_office/addMessage</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```